# Yii CListView - how to use the public property $template?

Tags: yii

I have this generated CListView code with some divs that I don't need.
I wish not to be absurd and hard code the class on zii/widgets.

I've seen this:

```
/**
     * @var string the template to be used to control the layout of various components in the list view.
     * These tokens are recognized: {summary}, {sorter}, {items} and {pager}. They will be replaced with the
     * summary text, the sort links, the data item list, and the pager.
     */
    public $template="{summary}\n{sorter}\n{items}\n{pager}";
```

It seems I can access $template and do something with it - can anyone please tell me, how can we remove the summary the sorter the items or the pager ?

Please advice.

Comment: Can you tell us which divs exactly you don't need?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove any of the `{placeholder}`s that you do not wish to render. To remove e.g. the sorter:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array( 
        // set up CListView like you want, and then:
        'template' => "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",
));
```

Comment: I've tried to make 'template' => "" (nothing inside) - but we get by default, {items} and {summary}. :(